# I'm trying to make a connect four game in Python. This is my code for printing the board. Running results in a list index out of range error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code so far:

```
grid = [["0","1","2","3","4","5","6"],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
itemNumber = 0
for listItem in range(len(grid)):
    line = ""
    elementNumber = 0
    for element in range(listItem):
        elementNumber = elementNumber + 1
        elementNumber = int(elementNumber)
        listItem = grid[[itemNumber][elementNumber]]
        line = line + str(listItem)
    print(line)
    itemNumber = itemNumber + 1
```

Running the code gives a list index out of range error on line 20. I don't understand why this is happening.

In addition, could anyone help me with finding a way to check if there is a win diagonally? I also need help with keeping the code running if someone, say, enters a column that doesn't exist.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and a huge thanks to any contributors in advance.

Comment: Please reformat the post so the code is in code format.

Comment: Nice attempt and welcome to Stack Overflow. This sounds like an educational project. I recommend breaking your code into some [functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) before going further. Functions will help you isolate problems and make your code reusable. `if` statements nested 7 deep is a sure sign you're looking for a loop to check each column.

Comment: Please limit your postings to one question each.  Your "In addition" questions are beyond the original issue.  Also, you're asking for tutorial help, wich is beyond the purpose of Stack Overflow.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Comment: @Prune I'm sorry if I broke any rules. Could you recommend for me some sites where I could get the help I'm looking for?

Comment: Instead of saying "gives a list index out of range error on line 20", please paste the actual exception here. Especially since there's only 18 lines in what you pasted, so we have no way of knowing which is line 20 in your real code.

Comment: For tutorial help or other things outside the scope of your question, you might want to look at the Community section of python.org for mailing lists and IRC channels. If nothing else looks more appropriate, python-tutor, python-list, and Freenode #python are usually good starting places.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is that you're trying to access the array like

```
listItem = grid[[itemNumber][elementNumber]]
```

instead of

```
listItem = grid[itemNumber][elementNumber]
```

and maybe you want to add the +1 to your element number "after" you have accessed the value since you will never get the first column like that

the correct way to loop through your grid would be to do this instead:

```
itemNumber = 0
for x in range(len(grid)):
    line = ""
    elementNumber = 0
    for element in range(len(grid[itemNumber])):
        listItem = grid[itemNumber][elementNumber]
        elementNumber = elementNumber + 1
        line = line + str(listItem)
    print(line)
    itemNumber = itemNumber + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's where I think you're doing wrong:

```
listItem = grid[[itemNumber][elementNumber]]
```

The correct way to index list of lists is `list[x][y]`, so in your case should be `listItem = grid[itemNumber][elementNumber]`

And here's another problem in your code:

```
while "OOOO" or "XXXX" in grid == False:
if gridSeven[column] == "X" or "O":
```

These are wrong formats of conditions. `"OOOO"` is a non-empty string which already means True, so this while loop condition is always True. Similarly, `"O"` means true as well. Correct format should be something like this:

```
while "OOOO" not in grid and "XXXX" not in grid:
if gridSeven[column] in ["X","O"]:
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down your attempt to index the grid,

```
listItem = grid[[itemNumber][elementNumber]]
```

We first print the values of the variables; `itemNumber` and `elementNumber` are both 1 at this point.  That makes this expression

```
listItem = grid[[1][1]]
```

To evaluate the expression `grid[1][1]], we start with the index you gave,`[1][1]`; note the extra barckets.  Working from the inside out,`[1]`(the left-hand one) is a list with a single element, the integer`1`.  You now try to access an element of this list, element`1`.  However, since [1] is a list with only one element, its only valid index is`0`.

This is where your error shows up.  The proper assignment is

```
listItem = grid[itemNumber][elementNumber]
```

This will evaluate `grid[1][1]`, which is row 2, column 2 of your 7x7 grid.